# Should PHP code have spaces before operators?

Tags: php, code-formatting

I've seen a lot of code recently formatted as the following:

#### A:

```
if ($var=='test'){
    $var=Foo('blah'.$var1);
}else{
    // do something
}
```

Personally I don't like it and would prefer it as:

#### B:

```
if ($var == 'test') {
    $var = Foo('blah' . $var1);
} else {
    // do something
}
```

I think it's much more readable (note the addition of spaces).

Is there a general preference in the community or is one way better than another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective reasons for using spaces instead of tabs for indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649847/objective-reasons-for-using-spaces-instead-of-tabs-for-indentation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most important thing is to follow a standard and stick to it.

That said maybe you can [follow Zend's Framework standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) and they **use spaces**. Check [C.4.6](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.php-code-demarcation).

```
if ($a != 2) {
    $a = 2;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1. Clear answer. Although it should be noted that whatever standard you go with, make sure it's clearly readable. In that aspect, Zend seems to do pretty well.

Comment: Please take care to follow Zend in PHP, not C. Good god, those macros can make your head explode.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for spaces :)

but that's just my own standard, as long as you are consistent and your code is clear, it should be okay

Answer (score 2):

PHP is much like C in its syntax. As I use both, I tend to follow the same style.

For instance, keywords vs functions:

```
if ($foo) {
```

vs

```
MySuperDuperFunction($foo);
```

Then you come to a question of indentation:

```
switch ($bar) {
    case CONSTANT:
        more_code();
```

.. is much easier to read as

```
switch ($bar) {
case CONSTANT:
    more_code();
```

This indicates that the switch and the case are on the same level, which they are. It also helps avoid crazy indentation in yet-to-be-optimal switches.

Your style should illustrate the [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) of the language you are using. This gets strange with PHP as well as C, because both have forgiving parsers.

If you write something like this:

```
if($a==2&&b==1&&c>3)
{
```

I'm going to hunt you down and demand that you pay for my aspirin. The same would go for this:

```
if (
    a==2
     &&
    b==1
     &&
    c>3
)
{
```

... For God sakes man, its not LISP!

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of convetions that are stablished within your team.

The most famous conventions are Zend Framework and [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). You can also create your own, just make sure it is readible.

Personally, I use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The general advice would be to standardize the code formating, so it meets some best practices, and is widely known, instead of inventing something custom.

[**PSR-2**](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), the coding style guide would be the best well known approach, accepted by many. [here are **facts**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35649925/4354249), why it's good to keep the code formatting.